# Animation not working correctly in Safari?

Tags: css, animation, safari

For some reason my music section 'flip divs' are not displaying correctly? What is causing this?

1st image-safari-screenshot: [Reveals the back but not the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sibKF.jpg)

2nd image-chrome-screenshot: [Works beautifully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti9Jv.jpg)

```
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000px;
}
/* flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container {
  margin-right:0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}
/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    /* for firefox 31 */
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Here's a link to the test site - lengtest.com

Comment: Someone help plzzzz

Comment: I figured it out - missed out -webkit on backspace, transform and perspective hah